Analytically solving for compressible pressure drop through piping system
I am currently trying to solve for absolute pressure as a function of length along a pipe. I call this length x. Air is flowing at high speeds (~ Mach 0.5) through the pipe. Therefore I must update the absolute pressure and temperature of the air as it moves through the pipe, since $\frac{dP}{dx}$ depends on these. Right now I have a start but not sure how to continue. I want to write equations that can be solved in Python or Matlab, and the absolute pressure of the air plotted as a function of x.
$\dot{V}_{inlet}=1.0548=$volume flow rate of air at pipe inlet

$P_{atm}=100000=$atmospheric pressure at pipe outlet

$R_{air}=287=$specific gas constant of air

$T_{inlet}=295=$temperature of the air at the inlet

$\rho_{inlet}=P_{inlet}/R_{inlet}/T_{inlet}=$density of air at the inlet

$\dot m=\rho_{inlet}\dot{V_{inlet}}=$mass flow rate of air

$d=0.108=$inner diameter of pipe

$A=0.25*\pi*d^2=$cross-sectional area of pipe

$k=1.4=$ratio of specific heats of air

$\mu=2.08*10^{-5}=$dynamic viscosity of air

$\epsilon=.000046=$pipe roughness

$L_{end}=9.2=$length of pipe total

$f=\frac{1}{(-1.8log((\frac{\epsilon/D}{3.7})^{1.11}+\frac{6.9}{\rho V d/\mu})^2}=$E. Haaland friction factor

$\Delta P=f*\frac{L_{end}}{D}*\frac{\rho V^2}{2}=$pressure difference between inlet and outlet of pipe

$\frac{T_2}{T_1}=(\frac{P_2}{P_1})^{1-\frac{1}{k}}=$temperature difference between two locations in pipe
